# Webpack Issue with VueJS + TypeScript for PowerBI Custom Visualization

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am trying to use VueJS + TS to build my custom Viz. I am facing errors while setting up. Since I am not that accustomed to webpack, it took me some time to solve a few of the errors that I was facing but I am unable to resolve the following error.

Since the vue.config.js file is pretty long, sharing the code via my repo:
https://github.com/dhwanils95/vue-power-bi-visual

You can also check what various things I have tried via the commits. I have 3 sub-projects within the repo. One for pure PowerBI viz with webpack (Works), One base VueJS project with TypeScript (Works), third being the desired goal.

Giving a gist of the issue, the plugin uses:

```
externals: {
      "powerbi-visuals-api": 'null',
      "fakeDefine": 'false',
      "corePowerbiObject": "Function('return this.powerbi')()",
      "realWindow": "Function('return this')()"
},
```

and the following in the `plugins: []` configuration.

```
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        window: 'realWindow',
        define: 'fakeDefine',
        powerbi: 'corePowerbiObject'
      }),
```

This gives the following errors:

```
  Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fakeDefine' in '.....\node_modules\lodash':
  Error: Can't resolve 'fakeDefine' in '.....\node_modules\lodash'
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'realWindow' in '.....\node_modules\webpack\buildin':
  Error: Can't resolve 'realWindow' in .....\node_modules\webpack\buildin'
```

The even more bugging part is if I comment out the lines like this:

```
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        // window: 'realWindow',
        // define: 'fakeDefine',
        powerbi: 'corePowerbiObject'
      }),
```

The compilation is successful and the dev server runs, but the `pbiviz.json` file which should be available at `/assets/pbiviz.json` is not available and there are no errors in neither the terminal nor the console which means something is silently failing that makes this all the more difficult to debug.

If you intend to pull and run, I have added an additional script in the package.json, `start` which uses raw webpack and that works as expected but is not configured to run Vue while the usual `serve` which I override using the `vue.config.js` file with the configurations for the PowerBI viz.

Please do let me know if there is something that I am missing out or not aware of. 
Any thoughts or ideas would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.